# Starts With an S

Tags: riddle

I could be a knot, or an item of dress
A place to put boats, or a knitted stitch
A failure of grip, balance, or speech
A miscarried birth, or the passage of time

What word am I, starting with S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> slip (see [knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_knot), [dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_dress), [boat slip](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dockominium), [stitch knitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip-stitch_knitting)), [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeslip_(disambiguation)).

If it does not grip, it

> slips

A speech error is a

> slip of the tongue

I don't know about balance and miscarried birth